# How to use auto mapper with conditional statements

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a method like this and trying to read an excel file. I am doing some
triming and using some conditional statements column by column.
How can I use automapper to achieve the excelData.Add section to make it clean?

```
public List<ExcelFileModel> ProcessExcelFileData(IFormFile file)
{
    var excelData = new List<ExcelFileModel>();
    .....
    .....
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        counter++;

        excelData.Add(new ExcelFileModel
        {
            Section = decimal.TryParse(reader.GetValue(2)?.ToString()?.Trim(), out decimal _section) ? _section : null,
            CourseNumber = reader.GetValue(3)?.ToString(),
            Department = reader.GetValue(4)?.ToString(),
        });
    }

    if (excelData != null && excelData.Count > 0)
        return excelData;
}
```

Comment: Why is this NOT clean? If you delegate all of that information to the mapper, including having to pass a reader instance to it, how is that any less clean than what you have here?

Comment: I just shortened it. I have about 10 fields more. It does not meet sonarqube standard.

Comment: You might want to consider simply moving it to an extension method at that point. Refactoring it into a mapper is doable, but infinitely more difficult to debug and read.

Comment: Do you have sample code for the extension method or mapper?

Comment: sure thing. I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you can solve this in a reusable way with a simple extension method.

```
public static class MapperExtensions
{
    public static ExcelFileModel Map(this IExcelDataReader reader)
    {
        return new ExcelFileModel
        {
            Section = decimal.TryParse(reader.GetValue(2)?.ToString()?.Trim(), out decimal _section) ? _section : null,
            CourseNumber = reader.GetValue(3)?.ToString(),
            Department = reader.GetValue(4)?.ToString(),
        };
    }
}
```

You can then call it with the following:

```
excelData.Add(reader.Map());
```

Comment: I will try it out. This will still be within the loop right? Hopefully sonarqube will not complain about this again because we are pretty much moving this to a static class.

Comment: Correct, this would be within the loop.

Comment: I am using Exceldatareader 3.6.0 to read the excel file. reader.map is unable to access that extension method.

Comment: I defined my method like this. public static ExcelFileModel Map(IExcelDataReader reader)

Comment: you specifically need the `this` keyword.  See my update.

Comment: I am getting this error highlight Map in red. 'IExcelDataReader' does not contain a definition for 'Map' and no accessible extension method 'Map' 
accepting a first argument of type 'IExcelDataReader' could be found 
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I fixed the name space issue and now code compiles. I will run it now